# Adding a suffix to both elements in a list and to a variable at the same time

Tags: python, list, suffix

Say I have a list of strings:

```
myList = ['apple','banana','orange']
```

and another string saved into a single variable:

```
myVariable = 'fudge'
```

I want to add the suffix `_df2` to every element in `myList`, and also to `myVariable`. Therefore, I want my result to look like this:

```
>> myList
['apple_df2', 'banana_df2', 'orange_df2']

>> myVariable
'fudge_df2'
```

Currently I am achieving this with the following code:

```
myList = [fruit + '_df2' for fruit in myList]
myVariable = myVariable + '_df2'
```

I am wondering, however, since I am adding the same suffix both times, is there a way to sum these two steps up into one?

Comment: There's no way to do it in one step (in one line possibly, but that's not a good solution). Though if you want to DRY, just put your suffix into the variable. Apart from that, your way is optimal.

Comment: They appear to be separate, unrelated operations. I think the best you could do is save `'_df2` into a variable so you don't need to change it in multiple places in the future. Otherwise, I'd do it as you already are.

Comment: Thanks! @YevhenKuzmovych Why is putting it into one line a bad solution?

Comment: @phoebe_albeduddel There's absolutely no benefit of doing that. It only worsens readability.

Comment: Thanks to everyone. I will just keep it as a two-liner.

Answer (score 0):

Create a single list headed by your singleton item, universally apply the modification, then unpack in the same order.

```
myVariable, *myList = [x + '_df2' for x in [myVariable, *myList]]
```

I would probably still prefer the two-line solution, though. You aren't *just* appending the same value to each element; you also need to preserve the list structure of the original list.

Comment: Star assignments are covered in [PEP 448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/) Works the other way too: `*myList,myVariable=[e+addition for e in myList+[myVariable]]`

Answer (score -1):

You could do the following, but as @YevhenKuzmovych says, its not a good solution.

```
myList, myVariable = [fruit + '_df2' for fruit in myList], myVariable + '_df2'
```

Comment: There's absolutely no benefit of doing that. There are still two operations there (3 or 4 if you count packing, unpacking). And now it's less readable.